# Is there a specific process to enable CORS on AWS VM's?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, http, post

I have a website that makes POST requests to a discord webhook, and I am getting CORS errors. I do not get these errors when running the site on my local machine. Is there something I am missing in my security groups or networking setup? This is my first time really using AWS.

Edit 1:
Here is the code:

```
function sendData(data){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","*");
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({content:String(data), username:"Name"}));
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're setting *request* headers. CORS headers are **response** headers. Your code can't give itself permission to access other websites, that would make the security feature pointless. `discordapp.com` needs to send the headers in the response. Code running on an AWS VM isn't subject to CORS/the Same Origin Policy in the first place though, only code running in a browser is.